# Can I manage the githhub page's index.html in templates?

Tags: spring-boot, github-pages

I understand that github's policy requires index.html to be in root. I run the project with springboot and when the index is in the root, it is cumbersome to manage, and I want to use the index.html of the templates. Of course, you can also create and forward a dummy file in the project root, but the domain does not come out neatly. Is there a way?

Comment: It's also a problem when passing a variable to the html from a controller. Or is there a way to pass variables from the controller to root's index.html?